# Xcode: Check whether email was send or canceled

Tags: cocoa-touch, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I want to make a `login` with an email registration and for that I have to check whether the user clicked on "*send*" or "*cancel*".
Is there any possibility to check this? Cause if the user doesn't send it I don't want that he comes in my app.
regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use default `MFMailComposeViewController` try to check '`(MFMailComposeResult)result`' in:

```
// Then implement the delegate method
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}




enum MFMailComposeResult {

   MFMailComposeResultCancelled,

   MFMailComposeResultSaved,

   MFMailComposeResultSent,

   MFMailComposeResultFailed

};
typedef enum MFMailComposeResult MFMailComposeResult;
```